# useState in react is not updating the state object

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have created a stateObject and updating the state whenever there is a data change in the input form.I wanted to clear the value in "error" key whenever the user type in the input form.

I tried setting the error key to null using the setState in the first step.However it is not working.
But when i try the same in the second step  error key is updating to empty string properly.I couldn't figure why the second step works and not the first step. Could someone explain this ?

```
const [userdata,setuserData] = useState({name:"",email:"",password:"",error:""});

const {name, email, password , error } = userdata;

//runs when the onchange click event works

const handleChange = (name)=> (event) =>{
    setuserData({...userdata,error:""}) // First Step- This line is not working
    setuserData({...userdata,[name]:event.target.value,error:""}); //Second Step - This is working
}

return (
<div className="container">
    <h2 className="mt-5 mb-5">Signup</h2>
    
    {/* inline Conditional Rendering*/}
    <div className="alert alert-primary" 
         style={{display:error ? "" : "none"}}>
        {error}
    </div>

    <form>
        <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Name</label>
                <input 
                onChange={handleChange("name")}
                value={name}
                type="text" className="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Email</label>
                <input 
                onChange={handleChange("email")}
                value={email}
                type="email" className="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
                <label className="text-muted">Password</label>
                <input 
                onChange={handleChange("password")}
                value={password}
                type="password" className="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-raised btn-primary"
        onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
</div>  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State setting is asynchronous and batched. The previous `userdata` doesn't get updated immediately when you call `setuserData`. As a result, only the *final* call of `setuserData` results in the new state on next render.

You need to set both properties at once in a single call (either that, or use the callback form instead):

```
setuserData({
  ...userdata,
  error: '', // or null?
  [name]: :event.target.value,
});
```

Use something like the above, *once*, or use:

```
setuserData(userdata => ({ ...userdata, error: '' }));
setuserData(userdata => ({ ...userdata, [name]: event.target.value }));
```

(but that second version is unnecessarily repetitive; the first option is preferable when possible)